# Android: how to use dip (density independent pixel) in code?

Tags: android

How do I specify that an `int` parameter is in dip? Specifically, how would write the equivalent of:

```
android:layout_width="50dip" 
android:layout_height="50dip"
```

Something like...:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(50, 50)
```

Answer (score 18):

There is a built-in method that will do this too: [TypedValue.applyDimension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)).

```
// Convert from 50dip to actual pixels
final int width = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
final int height = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height);
```

You can use this to convert from `sp` units to pixels as well.

Comment: I always thought this was a lack of functionality in Android. It seems it's not lacking, just not very pretty. :D