# Android Java determine pixel density in code

Tags: android, animation, pixel

I have a following animation:

```
    ImageView fallingLeave = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lemonpiece1_large);
                   mButtonProxy = AnimatorProxy.wrap(fallingLeave);

                   // Set up the path we're animating along
                   AnimatorPath path = new AnimatorPath();
                   path.moveTo(0,0);
                   path.curveTo(0, 0, 0 , 80, -80, 70);
                   fallingLeave.setRotation(80);
                   path.curveTo(-80, 70, -80, 120, 80, 140);
                   path.curveTo(80, 140, 80, 190, -80, 210);


                   // Set up the animation
                   final ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "buttonLoc",
                           new PathEvaluator(), path.getPoints().toArray());
                   anim.setDuration(2000);


                   anim.start();
```

Problem is that path is set fixed in pixels. What I want to do is to set the path pixel independent. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

I tried to link the variable to dimensions.xml, but It didnt work, I would rather MULTIPLY the pixel path with a pixel density ratio, but I dont know whethere there is a function that can return a value of a density ratio for a device.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `[Context.getResources.getDimensionsPixelSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize(int))` has never failed. Maybe you could detail why that is not working for you. But it's the approach to follow as it's more configurable to work with that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android) an answer that will probably be helpful. 
From the answers there it looks like this is the line you're looking for

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what Ive been looking for

Answer (score 1):

Even I had real trouble trying to achieve this.You can make it pixel independent specified in "dip" or "dp" units.

This link should be a good start :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

also refer to these posts:

[What is the correct way to specify dimensions in DIP from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code)

[Android: how to use dip (density independent pixel) in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669747/android-how-to-use-dip-density-independent-pixel-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

Now use [`dm.xdpi()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#xdpi) and [`dm.ydpi()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#ydpi) to get the pixel density in the X and Y dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DisplayMetrics class found here: [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

and use the density field

> The logical density of the display. This is a scaling factor for the Density Independent Pixel unit, where one DIP is one pixel on an approximately 160 dpi screen (for example a 240x320, 1.5"x2" screen), providing the baseline of the system's display. Thus on a 160dpi screen this density value will be 1; on a 120 dpi screen it would be .75; etc.

Hope it helps.