# Admob - Not enough space to show ad wants

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated Admob which is serving DFP ads. Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/headerAdLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
               android:id="@+id/adView"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               ads:adUnitId="/4359979/Top"
               ads:adSize="BANNER"
               >

           </com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I then explicitly set the ad sizes prior to loading the ads to try to ensure that there is enough space. I have additionally ensured that there is no padding both to the left and the right

```
PublisherAdView mAdView = (PublisherAdView) header.findViewById(R.id.adView);
mAdView.setMinimumWidth(720);
mAdView.setMinimumHeight(404);
mAdView.setAdSizes(new AdSize(720, 404));
PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

However I still get this message in Logcat:

```
Not enough space to show ad. Needs 720x404 dp, but only has 533x404 dp.
```

My screen width is being reported as 800 using the following code. (am running in landscape mode on a Samsung S4 mini device)

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
 Point size = new Point();
 int width = display.getWidth();
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: What you are getting is the width in pixels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels not density independent pixels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669747/android-how-to-use-dip-density-independent-pixel-in-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not enough space to show ad. Needs 720x404 dp, but only has 533x404
>   dp.

but your device is reporting **800 pixels**, `pixels` is not the same as `dp` so based on the Screen density of your device

- .75 on ldpi (120 dpi)
- 1.0 on mdpi (160 dpi; baseline)
- 1.5 on hdpi (240 dpi)
- 2.0 on xhdpi (320 dpi)
- 3.0 on xxhdpi (480 dpi)
- 4.0 on xxxhdpi (640 dpi)

you will calculate how many `dp` is really reporting your device, for example with a Screen Density of 2.0:

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160) = 800/(320 / 160) = 400 dp (404dp)
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem with NativeExpressAdView. I think, it's not a good idea to fix the ad's size width. I sugger to do in programmatically

1. First step : get the dp size of screen witdh

   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
               //float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
                dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

2. Second step:

if you don't have margin or padding in your layout

mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize((int) dpWidth, 150));

else

mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize((int) dpWidth-sumofpadding, 150));